# Using a variable string in find condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, conditional-statements

I have a string variable as follows:

```
the_style = @house.style   # this is a string variable and contains the value "modern"
```

If I search in the database as follows:

```
Building.find(:last, :conditions => [" style = ?", "#{the_style}" ])
```

I get an error with the above, however if I hardcode in the string value it works:

```
Building.find(:last, :conditions => [" style = ?", "modern" ])
```

What is the correct way to put the string variable into a find condition?

Comment: What error do you get? What version of Rails are you using? What you are trying *should* work, so there must be something wrong with your variable. Just one small note: `"#{the_style}"` is the same as `the_style`. It's useless to put your variable in quotes like that.

Answer (score 1):

Why use quotes just to escape from them?

```
Building.find(:last, :conditions => [" style = ?", the_style ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what's causing the error exactly, but I'd make a named scope for this sort of thing

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_style, lambda { |style| where("style = ?", style) }
  # ...
end
```

in your controller, you can then do

```
Building.by_style(@house.style).last
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `where` method:

```
Building.where(style: @house.style).first
```